# How can I stop Emacs from starting a browser when I save a file in HTML mode?

Tags: emacs, archlinux, html-mode

How can I stop Emacs 24.2 from starting a browser when I save a file in HTML mode?

Just upgraded my Archlinux installation. Now every time I save an html file I get a new instance of Konquerer.

Comment: Emacs does not do this by default.  Check your init file and installed packages.

Answer (score 12):

It's probably html-autoview-mode (a minor mode). Turn it off with `M-x html-autoview-mode`.

Comment: Yep, this.  I turned it on by fat-fingering something else and was really confused for a while...